# Не открывает pdf по ссылке в мазиле

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер

Что прописать в htaccess для того чтобы, если браузер не может открыть PDF, он его скачивал?

Comment: Если мозилла не настроена открывать PDF в браузере - хоть что прописывайте, не откроет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов о том и речь, я хочу чтобы он скачивался, если не может открыться.

Comment: Тогда непонятна суть проблемы

Comment: Вообще-то это и есть поведение по умолчанию для данного MIME. Если ничего не меняли - то будет открываться именно так, как написано в вопросе. В связи с этим вопрос: в чём проблема?

Comment: может в мазиле был глюк. вроде все работает.